# Console Application - get the values in an object

Tags: c#, json, console-application

I am unable to get the values in an object. I want to get the values of AEVL2020 or AEVL2021 in 'registers' object. But, before that I have to select first in 'devices' in which deviceSerialId first ex.  AEVL2020 or AEVL2021 and it will return the values based on registers.

Here is my json:

```
{
    "devices": {
        "AEVL2020":{
            "deviceSerialId": "AEVL2020"
        },
        "AEVL2021":{
            "deviceSerialId": "AEVL2021"
        }
    },
    "registers":{
        "AEVL2020":{
            "12":{
                "user_id": "1",
                "employee_id": "12",
                "name": "Juan Dela Cruz"    
            }
        },
        "AEVL2021":{
            "29":{
                "user_id": "1",
                "employee_id": "29",
                "name": "Maria Del Mundo"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I input AEVL2021 in console I get a correct result "29":{"user_id": "1","employee_id": "29", "name": "Maria Del Mundo"} but, the PROBLEM is when I input AEVL2020 I've got a result the same with AEVL2021. How should I fix this?

Here is my c#:

```
 using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(item.jsonPathFileName))
                    {
                        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                          dynamic jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
                   var register1 = jsonObject["registers"]["AEVL2020"].ToString();
                   var register2 = jsonObject["registers"]["AEVL2021"].ToString();

                        if (register1 == "AEVL2020")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(register1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(register2);
                        }
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected (using your debugger) what is the value of `register1`? Of course it's not `AEVL2020`, so your `if` condition is never `true` and you always print what's in `register2`. Why don't you deserialize to a class structure, you may find it easier to read the properties values.

Comment: You're right. There is no value in register1